# How to check the current selected date whether lies between the dates which already stored in database table?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

How to check the currently selected date whether lies between the dates store in a database table

I am working on the Leave management system. Suppose Empid=00001, and he had taken leave for 8 days from 30-05-2019 to 06-06-2019 and these data saved in a database table. Now again if the same Empid=0001, try to apply leave between 30-05-2019 to 06-06-2019 again, suppose he is trying to apply one day leave 03-06-2019 to 03-06-2019 which lies between above date. So it should check first that for this employee record there is a leave from 30-05-2019 to 06-06-2019 already in the database. So it shouldn't allow the employee to apply for any other leave on this date duration.

LeavefromDate -- table column
StartDate-- a variable that holds current leave start date.
EndDate--a variable that holds current leave End date.

My database is in sqlite3.

Looking for the perfect SQLite query to work

```
Select * from empleave where Empcode ='" + txtLeaveempcode.Text + "' and 
IsUploaded='0' and (date(substr(LeavefromDate, 7, 4) || '-' || 
substr(LeavefromDate, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(LeavefromDate, 1, 2) ) between '" +
 StartDate + "' and '" + EndDate + "') OR (date(substr(LeavefromDate, 7, 4) || 
'-' || substr(LeavefromDate, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(LeavefromDate, 1, 2) ) 
between '" + StartDate + "' and '" + EndDate + "');
```

not getting any date record.

Comment: what value you have in `LeavefromDate` ? is it a C# variable or Database column? Do you have any column in database to indicate `LeaveEndDate` ?

Comment: LeaveFromDate is a database table column which contains all leave start dates for a particular record, yes I have LeaveToDate which contains all leave end dates for the particular record.  here StartDate and EndDate are variables which contain Date which needs to be check from LeaveFromDate table column.

Comment: Why compare against only `LeaveFromDate` column, why not `LeaveToDate` also?